# RestSharp no cookies on response object

Tags: c#, cookies, restsharp

I'm having an issue trying to write a bot for a simple browser game.

The game can be found here http://en.gladiatus.gameforge.com/game/.

The problem is that after I login, i need to get the cookie that is going to be used on future requests, but the RestResponse.Cookies is always empty.

Here's a working login code that should illustrate my problem.

```
public bool DoLogin() {
    var client = new RestClient("http://s2.en.gladiatus.gameforge.com"); //Server 2 on England.
    var request = new RestRequest( "/game/index.php?mod=start&submod=login", Method.POST );
    request.AddHeader( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
    request.AddParameter( "name", "bot_test"); //test account.
    request.AddParameter( "pass", "bot_test_pass");

    var response = client.Execute( request );

    var match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match( 
        response.Content, 
        "href=\"index\\.php\\?mod=news&submod=serverEvents&sh=([^&]*?)\"" );

    var _Successful = match.Success;

    MessageBox.Show( response.Cookies.Count.ToString() ); //Always 0

    if(!_Successful) //Could not login.
        return false;

    var _SecureHash = match.Groups[0].Value;

    return _Successful;
}
```

I tried everything that I know (which is not much) but I couldnt find what is wrong with my code.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Try inspecting the response using a web traffic debugger (such as Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler ): chances are you do not receive any cookies in the response.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Doing the same thing with a browser I receive a cookie though. Gonna check why is that now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a `CookieContainer` on your RestClient before executing any requests:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://s2.en.gladiatus.gameforge.com");
client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
```

Then make sure you re-use the same RestClient instance in subsequent requests, and the same cookies will be passed automatically with each request.